# Using SSIS to connect to Access 365 Error 0x80040E09

Tags: ssis, oledb, ms-access-2016

I have three Access database MDB files with various tables I need to upsize to SQL Server. I need to be able to update the data regularly.

I am using an SSIS package in Visual Studio. I have it set to use the 32-bit version for this project. I have one of the databases running just fine.

Using the same techniques on the next database, I create an OleDb connection manager using the Access 16 connection and the connection tests fine, I drop down the tables drop down and it finds the table names just fine. I pick a table and hit <kbd>OK</kbd> and it comes back with:

> Exception from HRESULT:OxC0202038

Answer (score 0):

I got these databases from another source.  Two of the three were set without security.  Being older MDB's they have the ability to have user level security.  The table in question was in the one database that had security set to admin only.

The deceiving part is that the oledb connection could find the table names at all with security set, so I should not be able to read them.  The ambiguity of the error message was not all that helpful either.

But, once I reset the user level security to allow full access, things worked fine.